# Where to find Woocommerce Digital product data in database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to move my woocommerce Digital download website to a PHP-based site which is developed by me. That's why i want to get all downloadable product data from the database with the downloadable file Link. But, i am not able to find it in the database. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

the download products have an entrie `_downloadable_files` on the `_postmeta` for each downloadable products.

So you can select all downloadable products with this request :

```
SELECT `post_id`, `meta_value` FROM `dbprefix_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='_downloadable_files';
```